# Next JS 13 scroll restoration not working

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13, infinite-scroll, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am using Next JS 13.4.9 and scroll restoration isn't working at all on the following case same for  tag. I am not using scroll=false anywhere.

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
const router = useRouter();
router.push("/home");
```

Scroll down the home page that has dynamic Image/videos/text posts (just like facebook feed) -> click on a single post -> press back button on browser the feed starts again from the start of the page.

All of are on client side. Any ideas?

Next JS documentation mentions that it automatically restores it not sure what's wrong.